# how do i head to the beginning of a loop after a wrong answer in python?

Tags: python

```
print("What's your name?")
name = input('Answer: ')

while False:
    if name == 'joshua':
        print("you're right")
    else:
        print("you're wrong")

input('the end\n')
```

Comment: set a boolean flag and make that the condition of your while loop. i.e `incorrectAnswer = true; while incorrectAnswer: if name == 'joshua': incorrectAnswer = false`

Comment: `while False:` will never execute at all.

Comment: Note:  Avoid infinite loops.  Add another condition to exit the loop.  In this case maybe if guesses > 20.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `while False:`, you never get inside the loop at all
2. Your problem with the loop body isn't getting back to the top; it is that you haven't specified a way to *exit* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a boolean variable outside of the loop which will run basically forever until the answer is correct. You need to ask for input again in each iteration:

```
print("What's your name?")

unanswered = True

while unanswered:
    name = input('Answer: ')
    if name == 'joshua':
        unanswered = False
        print("you're right")
    else:
        print("you're wrong")

input('the end\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while True:` to loop infinitely, then break out of the loop when the answer is correct.

```
while True:
    print("What's your name?")
    name = input('Answer: ')
    if name == 'joshua':
        print("you're right")
        break
    else:
        print("you're wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use break and continue inside your while loop. [Control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

```
while True:
    if name != "Joshua":
        continue
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

That loop will never enter because its condition is always `False`. You'll need an extra variable to keep track. Start off by setting `correct = False` above the loop and changing your loop condition to `not correct`. Then, if they are correct, set `correct = False`.

You could also `break` on a right answer with `True` for the loop condition, but since I'm guessing you are new to programming, learning more traditional control flow would probably be better.